# How to resolve AOT-compiled for 32-bit architectures in Xamarin?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, syncfusion

I have been stuck with the same bug the last few days when archiving for Xamarin.iOS. When I archive for iOS, it would take about 6-8 minutes before showing me the following error below.

MyProject.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/armv7/Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable.dll.s(1168720,8): error GDC116A36: can not encode offset '0x100FD98' in resulting scattered relocation.

The assembly 'Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable.dll' can't be AOT-compiled for 32-bit architectures because the native code is too big for the 32-bit ARM architecture.

I followed Microsoft forums and found that it was a Xamarin bug that should be resolved within the latest version. I have the latest Xcode 11.3.1 and latest Xamarin (Visual Studio 8.4.1) and I'm still getting errors.

I tried deleting obj and bin to and cleaning my solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you compiling for 32 bit?  Apple requires 64 bit for all devices now

Comment: @Jason You're absolutely correct. I switched to "Supported Architectures" to ARM64 and I was able to archive. Can you please answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple now requires all apps to be 64 bit.  Be sure you that don't have any old 32 bit architectures selected in your project build settings.

Comment: you may still be targetting iOS 10 which requires 32-bit.